# query find and then insert if not exist but exist it will update

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, where-clause

i want find some fields and then create if not exist but if exist it will update. i try this query

> REPLACE INTO `tbl_master_data` (`part_number` ,`description`, `rrp`, `discount_code`, `product_group`, `value_discount`, `stk`) VALUES ('1100000-ax08', 'aas', 45, 'STD', 'ACC',50) WHERE `part_number`= '1100000-ax08';

but something wrong in where clause.
can tell me how it's work?

Comment: Do you want to insert a row if there is no data with `part_number` and update the data with `part_numbe = ...`?

Comment: exactly, you right how make it's possible?

Comment: I think this post will help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)

Comment: i have fileds part_number it's not primary key

Comment: See INSERT syntax